# UWP Communication with SQL Server Using .Net Standard 2.0

Tags: sql-server, uwp

I want to communicate my UWP application with SQL Server without WCF. Unfortunately there is no way of doing this.

However I found that .Net Standard 2.0 will have `System.Data` namespace. Will they support SQL Server communication?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Yes.

.NET Standard 2.0 will include the SqlClient namespace that lets you connect to and query an SQL Server database.

Comment: I think It belongs to `EFCore` not `.NET Standard 2.0`. Source: see Clint Rutkas [MSFT]'s command in [UWP SQL Server API](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/9327945-uwp-sql-server-api), [EntityFramework](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework)

Comment: You are wrong: "With the addition of .NET Standard 2.0 support for UWP with the Fall Creators Update...many of the most frequently used APIs like DataSet/DataTable, and popularly requested APIs like SqlClient, are now part of .NET Standard 2.0": https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/05/19/introducing-xaml-standard-net-standard-2-0/#TtXz5jIpGiVrwgEJ.97

Comment: Then what about `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` namespace in  [`EFCore`](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/dev/README.md)

Comment: Please ask a question if you have one. Don't ask questions in the comments field. This question is not about Entity Framework.

Comment: As my last command, I would like to say there is no `SqlClient` namespace in [`.NET Standard 2.0`](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/versions/netstandard2.0.md)

Comment: .NET Standard 2.0 is work in progress and the final version will include the SqlClient API as stated in the official blog post that I linked to.

Comment: I have read that article many days before. See the official [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/9064) by `.Net Core` on Github.

Comment: I don't know why you keep talking about .NET core. This question is about UWP and UWP vNext will support .NET Standard 2.0.

Comment: Did you read that issue? They are talking about bringing the `SqlClient` to UWP

Comment: .NET Standard 2.0 will bring the SqlClient to UWP vNext. That's the answer to the OP's question. If you have a question on your own, you should post it as a question and stop spamming the comments section :)

Comment: If you still don't believe me I recommend you to watch the following recording from Build 2017: https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2017/B8012

Comment: Ok, I will stop. This will be my last comment. I have watched that Build video. Plans can change.